# Symfony 4 use Entity from different namespace in annotation

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to use inside an entity another entity from another namespce but all I got is an error:

```
The class 'App\Entity\Gui\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Upv6
```

and the code:

```
namespace App\Entity\Upv6;
use App\Entity\Gui\User as User;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* ConfigSet
*
* @ORM\Table(name="config_set")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ConfigSetRepository")
*/
class ConfigSet
{
   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var User
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Gui\User")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", 
      nullable=false)
    */
    private $user;
```

Looks like it is still searching in same namespace.

Comment: You must tell in your doctrine.yml configuration all namespaces you are using

Comment: looks like your "App\Entity\Gui\User" this namespace is used in another place try to search. or try clear cache